# Production of $CO_2$ basal metabolism test

Tags: homework, metabolism, cellular-respiration

> Can the production of $CO_2$ be used as a type of basal metabolism test? Explain.

The answer to this is obviously yes, but I don't know how to explain it. Would the following be a good explanation?

> The faster your metabolism the more cellular respiration your cells do, and you produce more $CO_2$, so $CO_2$ output can be used as a type of basal metabolism test.

Comment: Yep, you got it.